# R function to segment data based on two columns?

Tags: r

I have a dataset that contains zip codes of houses and the price for each house. I need to split it into three datasets based on average price of the zip codes. For example, one set with the zip codes with the highest price, average price, and lowest price.

My idea was to order the dataset from lowest to highest based on price, split it into thirds, and then see where each zip code showed the most, but that feels inefficient. Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: Could you provide a sample data and the code you have written. Otherwise, SO users have difficulties in helping you out.

Comment: Here are your cutpoints. `price_grp <- quantile(  dset, price), (1:3)/3)`.  You could then classify zipcodes according to their proportions of high, medium and low prices. You will need to specify a particular rule for that classification. The `table` function should suffice. Perhaps sorting on the proportion of "high" prices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution that uses dplyr. It is a little bit verbose, but it gets the job done. Using group_by calculates mean prices for each postcode, so that you can more precisely split up according to expensive, average, and cheap postcodes.

```
library(dplyr)
# Generate sample data
dat <- tibble(postcode = sample(c("5432", "5654", "2342", "1231", "8543", "4324"), 1000, replace = TRUE),
                  price = rnorm(1000, 400000, 50000))

# Work out mean price for each postcode
mean_prices <- dat %>%  
    group_by(postcode) %>% 
    summarise(mean_price = mean(price))

# Find split points for the mean postcode price 
split_points <- quantile(unique(mean_prices$mean_price), (1:3)/3)

# Get the postcodes that are within cheap, middle, or expensive price ranges
cheap_postcodes <- mean_prices %>%     
    filter(mean_price <= split_points[1]) %>%
    pull(postcode)

middle_postcodes <- mean_prices %>%     
    filter(mean_price > split_points[1] & mean_price <= split_points[2]) %>%
    pull(postcode)

expensive_postcodes <- mean_prices %>%     
    filter(mean_price > split_points[2]) %>%
    pull(postcode)

# Create the three datasets 
cheap_third <- dat %>% filter(postcode %in% cheap_postcodes)

middle_third <- dat %>% filter(postcode %in% middle_postcodes)

expensive_third <- dat %>% filter(postcode %in% expensive_postcodes)
```

Comment: This makes a lot of sense to me! I'm new to R and thought there might be a helpful library but couldn't seem to figure out what to use. Thanks for your help!